# How to tell Angular's HttpClient to initialise all properties even if they are not returned from the server

Tags: angular

I'm using the Angular HttpClient to fetch an object from my server. The server responds with only the fields that are not null:

```
{
'valueA': 'A',
'valueB': 'B'
}
```

My TypeScript interface looks like this:

```
export interface MyObject {
  valueA: string;
  valueB: string;
  valueC: string;
}
```

I would expect that even if `valueC` is not provided by the server, Angular would still initialize `valueC`, but the object returned by the HttpClient has no property `valueC`. Is there a way to force Angular to use all properties from the interface?

Comment: The typings **do not** exist at runtime; they don't cause any kind of casting or conversion. If those props might not be on the object, they should be *optional* (e.g. `valueC?: string`) so the rest of your code can deal with it in a type-safe way. I'm trying to get this improved in the docs: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25401

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an automatic way to do this. You need to do it manually, though from your question, I'm not sure what valueC should be initialized to...  empty string? The other answer here would work, below is a different approach:

You could define a default object and assign it on retrieval:

```
const DEFAULT_MY_OBJECT = {
  valueA: '',
  valueB: '',
  valueC: '',
}

this.http.get<MyObject>(url)
    .pipe(map(r => Object.assign({}, DEFAULT_MY_OBJECT, r)));
```

but the commenter who said you should define your typings correctly is the best answer IMO.  If a property on a response is optional, it should be typed as such

Answer (score 1):

You can do a model like this:

```
export class MyObject {
    valueA: string;
    valueB: string;
    valueC: string;

    constructor(resp: { valueA: string; valueB: string; valueC: string; }) {
        this.valueA = resp.valueA;
        this.valueB = resp.valueB;
        this.valueC = resp.valueC;
    }
}
```

And then `map` response like this:

```
this.http.get(`http://something`, options)
    .pipe(
        map(resp => resp.map(a => new MyObject(a)))
    )
```

Comment: Just about there, you need to add default values to the resp objects properties to ensure they're assigned.  @Fip, what do you expect to happen?  How would angular or JavaScript know you want something assigned that isn't there?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers I figured out the following solution which works for me:

```
export class MyObject {
  valueA = '';
  valueB = '';
  valueC = '';

  constructor(obj: any) {
    Object.assign(this, obj);
  }
}
```

And my http client looks like this:

```
http.get(...).subscribe(res => {
 this.myobject = new MyObject(res);
}
```

Comment: I think you should mark one of the viable answers below as the correct answer. also, using pipe is the better way

Comment: It looks like you're calling `http.get` inside a component, which you shouldn't really be doing - see e.g. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4